# How can I get just cars objects from an array with different types of objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

How can I get only the `cars` objects in a new array or in a loop?

```
type ads = cars | mobiles ;
var add : ads[] = [];
add.push(new cars("Corolla", 800000, 2008));
add.push(new cars ("ferrari", 10000000, 2014));
add.push(new mobiles("nokia", 8000, 3310));
add.push(new cars("mehran", 21, 213));
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide an example of what you desire as the result.  Also, it would be helpful to include the code defining `cars` and `mobiles`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Array.prototype.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method together with the [instanceof operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof):

```
let carsArray = add.filter(item => item instanceof cars);
```

This will create a new array with just the cars instances in the `add` array.

[Complete example in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=class%20cars%20%7B%0A%09constructor(param1%3A%20string%2C%20param2%3A%20number%2C%20params3%3A%20number)%20%7B%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Aclass%20mobiles%20%7B%0A%09constructor(param1%3A%20string%2C%20param2%3A%20number%2C%20params3%3A%20number)%20%7B%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Atype%20ads%20%3D%20cars%20%7C%20mobiles%20%3B%0Avar%20add%20%3A%20ads%5B%5D%20%3D%20%5B%5D%3B%0Aadd.push(new%20cars(%22Corolla%22%2C%20800000%2C%202008))%3B%0Aadd.push(new%20cars%20(%22ferrari%22%2C%2010000000%2C%202014))%3B%0Aadd.push(new%20mobiles(%22nokia%22%2C%208000%2C%203310))%3B%0Aadd.push(new%20cars(%22mehran%22%2C%2021%2C%20213))%3B%0A%0Alet%20carsArray%20%3D%20add.filter(item%20%3D%3E%20item%20instanceof%20cars)%3B).

Comment: i just want the new cars object not also new mobiles object

Comment: Right, that's what this code does. The `carsArray` will only have the instances of `cars` which are included in the `add` array. The instances of `mobiles` won't be there.  Try the code in playground.